# mat-checkbox w/ selectionModel - checked attribute not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

After selecting the 5th checkbox, I expect the view to update by unchecking the mat-checkbox. However this is  not the case...  When I console.log, it returns the correct result, but the view/checkbox does not reflect this... Any ideas?

```typescript
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
              (change)="$event ? toggleRow(row) : null"
              [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
              [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
</mat-checkbox>
```

```typescript
  toggleRow(row) {
    console.log('selection before', this.selection.selected);
    this.selection.toggle(row);
    if (this.selection.selected.length >= 5) {
      this.selection.deselect(row);
    }
    console.log('selection.isSelected', this.selection.isSelected(row));
    console.log('selection after', this.selection.selected);
  }
```

Comment: What is `selection`. Can you please provide more information on the missing pieces of the code? Maybe creating a sample stackblitz replicating the issue would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to give a little timeout before deselect the check box. May be angular change detection mechanism could not be able to identify that change much quickly. Since you are performing deselect as soon as select the 5th checkbox.

```typescript
if (this.selection.selected.length >= 5) {
       setTimeout(() => {
          this.selection.deselect(row);
       }, 10);
    }
```

I do not know your situation well following may be also worked

```typescript
if (this.selection.selected.length >= 5) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.selection.deselect(row);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second option. I should have tried this as I know setTimeout is a common pattern when change detection is acting up.

Comment: No problem! glad it helps you!